# How can I make top navbar take 100% of the width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

How can I make top navbar take 100% of the width? I have tried many things, including setting width to 100% as well as using `<br>` after getting desperate. I also read that we should not use row with navbar and I tried to follow the best practise of using Container within Navbar. What's wrong with my thought process?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Navigation.css';
import Table from '../../assets/table/Table';
import TableGrouping from '../../assets/table/TableGrouping';
import Home from '../../pages/Home';

const Navigation = () => {
    return(
        <Navbar className="navbar pt-0 fixed-top>
            <Router>
                <Container> 
                    <Nav className="bg-custom col-12">
                        <Link className="nav-item" to="/">Home</Link>
                        <Link className="nav-item" to="/tableGrouping">Grouping</Link>
                        <Link className="nav-item" to="/table">Table</Link>
                    </Nav> 
                </Container>
                <br/>
                <Container>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                        <Route path="/tableGrouping" element={<TableGrouping/>}></Route>
                        <Route path="/table" element={<Table/>}></Route>
                    </Routes>
                </Container>
            </Router>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

Here is my style sheet:

```
.nav-item {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px 8px 20px; 
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.bg-custom {
    background-color: rgb(154, 166, 218);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<div class="Container">` in Bootstrap will certainly contain the width but you are using `<container>`. It might be a case of one or the other for Bootstrap to work for your advantage. Try removing that container/div and also check the result without your edited CSS as that may ultimately cause other Bootstrap styling problems later on.

Comment: What is your rendered HTML from the `Navbar` component?

Comment: To simply try it without the `<container>` but I would admit I do not know if it works.

Comment: Everything depends on the HTML rendered structure. Probably `Container` renders div with class="container", then what `Nav` component renders?

Comment: These comments are not meant for conversation Azu, how about you post the answer? Have a great weekend bro.

Comment: @Azu yes `<Container>` renders  `<div class="container">`